# File cache saving on Internal memory

Tags: android, image, caching, android-external-storage, internal-storage

I developed an android app which has blog post retrieve from RSS feed..
This post contain Title and Image of Blog Post.
I am saving image cache using following code:

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "LazyList");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url) {
    // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
    // demo.
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear() {
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return;
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}

}
```

But the problem is it only save cache when memory card present
I want both option for saving cache i.e either external storage /internal storage

Answer (score 0):

You just checking with getExternalStorage state is present and you created directory for cache in SD card alone... try to use below condition :

```
final String cachePath =
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
                !isExternalStorageRemovable() ? getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath() :
                        context.getCacheDir().getPath();

return new File(cachePath + File.separator + uniqueName);
```